# Some tools in PowerCenter Designer are deactivated. Why?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have 'Source Analyzer', 'Target Designer', 'Transformation Developer', 'Mapplet Designer' & 'Mapping Designer' tools deactivated in my 'PowerCenter Designer' tool.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to expect that. Open a folder, try creating a new mapping, and you should see them enabled right away.